# Python 3 - I can't print my sorted list using the .strip() function successfully

Tags: python, list, sorting, printing

I want to print a list one word per line, but when I print the sorted version I can't seem to do that. My textfile just has five words, one on each line,

```
dog
bit
mailman
cat
anteater
```

Everything is fine in terms of code, it's just solving how to print it out correctly.

```
def letterSort(wordlist):
    letterbin = [[] for _ in range(26)]
    final = []
    for line in open(wordlist):
        word = line.strip().lower()
        firstLetter = word[0]
        index = ord(firstLetter) - ord('a')
        bins = letterbin[index]
        if not word in bins:
            bins += [word]
    for bins in letterbin:
        insertion_sort(bins)
        final += bins
    return final        

def swap( lst, i, j ):

    temp = lst[i]
    lst[i] = lst[j]
    lst[j] = temp

def insert( lst, mark ):
    index = mark
    while index > -1 and lst[index] > lst[index+1]:
        swap( lst, index, index+1 )
        index = index - 1

def insertion_sort( lst ):

    for mark in range( len( lst ) - 1 ):
        insert( lst, mark )


def main():
    wordlist = input("Enter text file name: ")
    print("Input words:", )
    for line in open(wordlist):
        print(line.strip())
    print("\n")
    print("Sorted words:", )

    for line in open(wordlist):
        print(letterSort(wordlist.strip()))


main()
```

After all this this is the what I'm getting:

```
Enter text file name: wordlist.txt
Input words:
dog
bit
mailman
cat
anteater


Sorted words:
['anteater', 'bit', 'cat', 'dog', 'mailman']
['anteater', 'bit', 'cat', 'dog', 'mailman']
['anteater', 'bit', 'cat', 'dog', 'mailman']
['anteater', 'bit', 'cat', 'dog', 'mailman']
['anteater', 'bit', 'cat', 'dog', 'mailman']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `letterSort` returns a list. You cannot use `strip` on a list.

To print each element of a list on a new line, replace the last two lines in your `main` function with these:

```
for sorted_word in letterSort(wordlist):
    print sorted_word
```

In your last `for` loop, you are iterating over all the words in the file and calling the sort function that many times when you only need to call it once. This is why your sorted list is printed 5 times (as you have 5 lines in your file)

Comment: Works! I appreciate the clarification!